# Compare a value from two column and get matching value from another table Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am fairly new to *powerbi* and I need your help in one task on which I am stuck on.

Basically I have two tables and I need to compare the value from table one with a row of table 2 and return the output.

**Table 1**

[image]

I need to compare values in column *a & b* and get a match from table 2.
For example if row 1 has BY Green & BS HIGH then I need to check this value from matrix table below and return the output in column value as either 0 or 1.

**Table 2**

[image]

As you can see the Table 2 first row has value BY Green and BS low has a value '0'

Comment: 'By Green' is found in both col A and Col B? As are 'BS High' and 'BS Low' -- even if I could combine the two and lookup one to the other, how can I know which one 'Col A' to match in Table 2? eg if T1:Col A then then T2:Col A? or is it T2:Row 2? Although it appears the resulting elements are duplicated, 'BY Green'+'BS Low', just inverted, is this true, or just a coincidence?

Comment: hi jbowman, we need to check like this Table one 1st row has  BY Green in colA and BS High in colB. we need to look up the same value in matrix table two by first col. here we found BY Green in second row and when we scan the row of BYGreen we find BS LOW has value to be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

[image]

Index() returns a value from the matrix (in purple) based upon the intersections of the two match()'s. The first is the Vertical match in from the Table1:Col A; the second is the Horizontal match from table1:Col B. The value found at that intersection is returned.

... My apologies ... just saw this was a BI request... no worries...

First, Need fixup table2 as a lookup file:

First, click a cell in table 2 (don't edit), then Data menu >frm table/range, will bring up the Power Query window.  Select columns B (not A) through  Col F), then in the PQ Transform menu > Unpivot to create the new lookup table.  this can either be saved as a new table or be used by reference.

[image]

Next, open and merge Table 1 PQ_Table 2 (Be sure to select BOTH Columns in BOTH Tables, in the same order). Then, expand the table tab following the merge expand the table tab.  I only selected the value to return but you can return all the values to verify, then delete the unneeded columns.
[image]

Hope this helps...

Good Luck.